# How to get sum of a column in Zend framework using model and controller

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, tomato-cms

I am looking for a way to get the sum of a column. The query i am using looks like this:

```
public function gradeRound($rating)
    {
        $sql = mysql_query("Select SUM(rating) AS grades FROM" . $this->_prefix . "media_set_rating WHERE set_id = set_id");
        mysql_real_escape_string($rating->rating);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql); 
        $grades = $row['grades'];
    }
```

I am not sure how to get this properly formatted for the controller. right now my controller has this.

i put a text box on the page and echoed $grades - this is also included in the view as so:

```
$this->_view->assign('grades', $grades);
```

so that i can use it.

I tried replacing $setId with $rating both of which are being requested at the top.

I do not get anything out of my echo. I had -1 in there earlier. i am not sure where it was getting that from. I was trying different methods and got different results.

appreciate any hints or clues as to how to do this.
thanks

Revised 2:17 EST May 27 2013

Thanks Niko. I must be getting tired!

Here is the revised query:

```
    public function gradeRound($rating)
{
    $sql = sprintf("Select SUM(rating) AS grades FROM " . $this->_prefix . "media_set_rating 
                WHERE set_id = set_id");
    $sum = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sum); 
    $grades = $row['grades'];
    return $grades;
}


$grades = $setDao->gradeRound($setId);
```

Comment: dont forget to add extra space between `FROM` and `tableName`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by extra space?

Comment: it should be `"...FROM "`

Comment: Is this on a table class? (Extending Zend_Db_Table_Abstract?)

Comment: @JW just saw that. thanks Now i am just getting an empty error. Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/matrix/application/modules/media/models/dao/mysql/Set.php on line 83

Comment: @ Orangepill No not extending Zend_Db_Table_Abstract. This is kind of a different animal. it is based on Tomato CMS.

Comment: don't know about tomato but general ZF assigning to a view from the controller is `$this->view->grades = $grades;` ... assign works as well though but the view object is at `$this->view`

Comment: @Orangepill This controller is a Widget. That is Why there is a namespace in it.

Comment: It looks like you don't return anything from that method -- shouldn't there be a `return $grades;` at the very end?

Comment: @Niko - Thanks that did it! A few other changes that were made also. I will post my code updated at the top!

Comment: That "sprintf" part still looks a bit weird, are you sure that you're getting the correct results? You're nowhere using the argument `$rating`.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query looks rather odd. Depending on the type of "set_id", it is supposed to look like this:

```
mysql_query("
    Select SUM(rating) AS grades
    FROM " . $this->_prefix . "media_set_rating
    WHERE set_id = '". mysql_real_escape_string($rating->rating) ."'"
);
```

for ´$rating->rating` being a string. For an integer, it should be:

```
mysql_query("
    Select SUM(rating) AS grades
    FROM " . $this->_prefix . "media_set_rating
    WHERE set_id = ". (int) $rating->rating
);
```

And in total (adding also a return statement):

```
public function gradeRound($rating)
{
    // expecting "set_id" to be an integer field
    $result = mysql_query("Select SUM(rating) AS grades FROM " . $this->_prefix . "media_set_rating WHERE set_id = ". (int) $rating->rating);

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
    return $row['grades'];
}
```

Comment: I have tried what you have written and for whatever reason it does not work. I tried both. Not an issue though because what i do have works. I do have another stumbling block - I am creating another thread for it as it does not relate to this post. Thanks Again

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help You !

```
$select = $table->select();
$select->from ("table", array("date", "column1" => "sum(column1)"));
$select->group ( array ("date") );
```